# CakePHP Model belongsTo SQL Query

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm working on an old project that has been coded by someone who is no longer at the company, and the project has been made with `CakePHP 2.4.0` and I'm not super familiar with CakePHP.

I'm experiencing a weird problem where the belongsTo returns the wrong entry. I have three tables, Orders, Deals and Cities, which has the following structures.

## Orders

```
+----+---------+
| id | deal_id |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       1 |
+----+---------+
```

## Deals

```
+----+---------+
| id | city_id |
+----+---------+
|  1 |       2 |
+----+---------+
```

## Cities

```
+----+-----------+
| id |   name    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Montreal  |
|  2 | Toronto   |
|  3 | Ottawa    |
|  4 | Québec    |
|  5 | Vancouver |
|  6 | Calgary   |
|  7 | Halifax   |
+----+-----------+
```

Inside the `OrdersController`, when I try to retrieve the city name:

```
$this->Order->Deal->City->field('name');
```

I get `Calgary` instead of the expected `Toronto`. Therefore, I've taken a look inside the `City.php` which has a property of `orders`, and that explains why I'm receiving `Calgary` since it's ordering by the `name` of the city in ascending order. If I put the property in in comment, I get `Montreal` instead of `Toronto` since it's no longer ordering by the name.

I know my Deal has the right `city_id` because when I do the following, I get `2`:

```
$this->Order->Deal->field('city_id'); // 2
```

---

## City.php

```
class City extends AppModel
{
    public $order = "City.name asc";
}
```

## Deal.php

```
class Deal extends AppModel
{
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'City' => array(
            'className' => 'City',
            'foreignKey' => 'city_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Now my questions are:

1. Why is the wrong city returned from the relation?
2. How can I see the executed SQL query for my action?

I've tried getting the datasource of the model but it returns an empty log.

```
$log = $this->Order->Deal->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
```

---

## OrdersController

```
public function passengers($id = 0)
{
    $this->Order->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Order->exists()) {
        $this->redirect('/');
    }

    $name = $this->Order->Deal->City->field('name');
    var_dump($name); die;
}
```

Comment: `Model::field()` requires an id to be set beforehand, ie there should be more code. Also it issues a new query, and doesn't involve associations at all, so you're probably simply using the wrong method there - Please show the related code.

Comment: @ndm The controller has over 3000 lines... It's a mess, so I'll put the function that the route is calling.

Comment: That's what I ment. The `field()` usage is definitely incorrect, it is restricted to the very model where you call it on. I guess you want the name of the `City` associated (via `Deal`) with the `Order` that has the id `$id`?

Comment: @ndm Yes exactly. What do you mean it's restricted to the very model?

Comment: @ndm Oh so you mean when I do `$this->Order->Deal->City`, the `City` has no `id` set yet, therefore it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, `Model::field()` issues a new query to retrieve a single field from the database, restricted to the very model on which you call the method, ie it requires the `id` on `$this->Order->Deal->City` to be set, and then queries the `City` record with that ID, it has nothing to do with associations or already retrieved data.

If you want the name of the `City` associated (via `Deal`) with the `Order` that has the ID `$id`, then you either need to query on `$this->Order` and make sure that the `City` association is contained, or that the required `recursive` level is set:

```
$order = $this->Order->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('id' => $id),
    'contain' => 'Deal.City',
    // or
    // 'recursive' => 1
));

$name = $order['Deal']['City']['name'];
```

Or query on the `City` model and include the required joins that would restrict the record via the associated tables.

If you want to see the generated queries, enable debug mode in your `app/Config/core.php`, and for further insight install the Debug Kit plugin.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Core Libraries > Behaviors > Containable](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Models > Model Attributes > recursive](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive)**
- **[Cookbook > Models > Associations: Linking Models Together > Joining tables](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)**
- **[Cookbook > Configuration > CakePHP Core Configuration](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#cakephp-core-configuration)**
- **[Cookbook > Development > Debugging > Debug Kit](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/debugging.html#debug-kit)**

Comment: Oh wow, it's different from Laravel where you can just access the model instance. Good to know, thanks!